# Date saved as the date before

Tags: java, angularjs, postgresql, date

It's not a coincidence that this question has the same exact title as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266876/java-date-saved-as-the-day-before). Same problem, different environment.

My Angular-based application sends the Tomcat server a date taken from [Angular UI Calendar Picker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) in ISO format and UTC time zone, so that if I choose `May 1st 2016` in the `CEST` time zone it will be `Apr 30 22:00 +2` in JSON. And Postgres will save that wrong value too! Mysql, SQL Server and Oracle are not affected by this problem (explanation below)

Here is a step-by-step explanation of the round-trip

1. User selects `11/04/1956` in `dd/MM/yyyy` format
2. Client sends `"birthDate" : "1956-04-10T22:00:00.000Z"`
3. Spring MVC, using Jackson, will decode `Tue Apr 10 23:00:00 CET 1956`. Please note that Apr 30 should be in daylight saving already
4. Hibernate will save that data to Postgres on a column of type `java.util.Date` annotated with `@Temporal(DATE)`
5. Postgres will store `1956-04-10` in that column
6. Spring requests via Ajax a JSON representation of the entity, and that contains `"birthDate" : "1956-04-10"` in the body

Additional considerations:

- I have already faced and solved the problem in other DBs by setting Tomcat time zone. Not really the smartest solution ever, because imposing `-Duser.timezone` requires exact synchronization with client time zone, which is not possible in an international environment, which ours is *not* - I mean we are lucky all our customers are from the same location, no matter London Rome or Paris
- The issue does happen **only** when date fields strip the time. I mean if we store a column as datetime to only keep the track of the date, it will always be presented correctly
- I have already read [this bug](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2072) but it provides no helpful information
- Worse, I need this problem solved or worked around due to time constraints. Manually editing DB entries where incorrect is the last stand

I have little experience with Postgres anyway.

Is there any option to force Postgres timezone from JDBC or Hibernate properties? (workaround)

Or what is the correct solution to this kind of issue?

Comment: What is your exact time zone? (CEST isn't a real time zone ID... it's a sort of half-time-zone-abbreviation which would apply in lots of different time zones.)

Comment: Why does your date picker add time information anyway?

Comment: CEST is CET+1. Daylight saving time in CET https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cest

Comment: @RealSkeptic because of the already mentioned issue in AngularUI i guess?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I also checked Angular UI code, it massively uses Javascript's "new Date" function. See this example http://plnkr.co/edit/4uTkLY?p=preview where I omitted date formatting

Comment: I'm not an Angular expert, but I do believe you have to fix this on the Javascript side and then you won't have problems on the UI side. E.g. use a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) to get the shortened string from the date.

Comment: Actually filter is not the real issue, because filter works on display. We are trying to hack the directive itself to fix time to noon. I have posted on the bug too with reference to the GWT SO question. Trying to close the circle... hopefully before 11... PM... Central Europe Summer Time of course :-)

Comment: Filter doesn't have to work on display, you can filter an object and put the resulting string in the JSON instead of the full date and time string.

Comment: I agree with @RealSkeptic: there must be a way Angular can be set up to pass this date as a string. Have you thought about putting a bounty on this question? It is now eligible for one.

Comment: (If it is easier, you could always add a few hours to your JS time before sending it, so any TZ adjustments within your European zones do not make any difference. A horrible hack, but may be easier than changing types in Angular).